# Cyclically moving elements in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So I have this assignment I need to do, and it goes as follows:

Write a void premakni() method that cyclically moves the elements of the table so that the smallest element is first in the table, but the order of the elements does not change.
When implementing a method, you must not create and use any new tables and you must not use any additional Java classes (eg for working with tables or strings).

I have tried multiple solutions and I cant get the hang of it. Here are some test examples I have:
test:

```
int[] a={0,1,2,-1,-2};
int[] b=premakni(a);
System.out.println(izpisiTab(a));
System.out.println(izpisiTab(b));
```

result:
0 1 2 -1 -2
-2 0 1 2 -1

test:

```
int[] a={8,5,6,2,1,-1,-100,425,84};
int[] b=premakni(a);
System.out.println(izpisiTab(a));
System.out.println(izpisiTab(b));


result:
8 5 6 2 1 -1 -100 425 84
-100 425 84 8 5 6 2 1 -1
```

"izpsiTab" is a method that just prints out the array.
Can someone give me some ideas on how I should do this?

My current code is this:

```
public static void premakni(int[] tabela) {
        int minValueIndex = 0;
        int minValue = tabela[0];

        // Find the minimum element and its index in the array
        for (int i = 1; i < tabela.length; i++) {
            if (tabela[i] < minValue) {
                minValue = tabela[i];
                minValueIndex = i;
            }
        }

        // Shift the elements to the left
        for (int i = minValueIndex; i > 0; i--) {
            tabela[i] = tabela[i - 1];
        }

        // Place the minimum element at the first position
        tabela[0] = minValue;
        
    }
```

But then I get errors because this is a void function and in the tests I have "int[] b=premakni(a);" and I cant put anything in b this way. Also my code changes the "a" array, but it should stay the same

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way is to just find the minimum value and it's position and then rotate so the value is at location `0`.  Finding the minimum position is done in linear time.  The long pole is the rotation.  With a single direction rotation, `N` rotations would be required where `N` is the `position` of the `lowest value`.  Using another array would speed up the process but since that is not permitted, providing `left` and `right` rotation methods would minimize the rotations required.  If the min cell is beyond the middle, rotate to the right.  Otherwise, rotate to the left.

```
int[] arr = {8, 5, 6, 2, 1, -1, -100, 425, 84};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotateToMin(arr)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotateToMin(new int[] {3,2,1})));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotateToMin(new int[] {1,2,3})));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotateToMin(new int[] {-1,-10,2})));
```

prints

```
[-100, 425, 84, 8, 5, 6, 2, 1, -1]
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[-10, 2, -1]
```

- Start by just finding the minimum and save its position
- the rotate to that position.

```
public static int[] rotateToMin(int[] arr) {
     int pos = 0;
     int min = arr[0];
     for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
         if (arr[i] < min) {
             min = arr[i];
             pos = i;
         }
     }
     if (pos > arr.length / 2) {
           rotateRight(arr, arr.length-pos);
     } else {
           rotateLeft(arr, pos);
     }
     return arr;
}
```

Left and right rotation methods.  There may be fancier ways of doing this but providing two distinct methods was the most straightforward.

```
private static void rotateLeft(int[] arr, int count) {
    for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
            int save = arr[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            }
            arr[arr.length - 1] = save;
        }
    }
```

right rotation by count cells

```
private static void rotateRight(int[] arr, int count) {
    for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) { 
    int save = arr[arr.length-1];
          for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                arr[i] = arr[i-1];
          }
          arr[0] = save;
    }
}
```

Note: since you're modifying a passed array it is not required to return it.  I just did it for ease of demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1: Identify the smallest element and get the index.**

```
static int findTheSmallestElementIndex(int ar[]) {

    int index = 0;
    int min = ar[0];

    for(int i=1; i<ar.length; i++) {

        if(min > ar[i]) {
            min = ar[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

**Step-2: Use that index to calculate the number of rotations required.**

```
int numberOfRotations = ar.length - findTheSmallestElementIndex(ar);
```

**Step-3: If the smallest element is already at the first index the `numberOfRotations` will be `0` and so no need to do anything, just return the array.**

**Step-4: Array rotation to the right by one explained.**

1. Take the backup of the rightmost element in the array, the last element (`int temp = ar[ar.length-1];`). If you are rotating to the left choose the leftmost element, the first element.
2. Start a for loop from the last index of the array and stop it right before the first index. (`for(int i=ar.length-1; i>0; i--)`)
3. Replace the element from the current index with the one just behind it. (`ar[i] = ar[i-1];`). So your array `[8, 5, 6, 2, 1, -1, -100, 425, 84]` after the loop will be transformed like this `[8, 8, 5, 6, 2, 1, -1, -100, 425]`
4. Replace the first element with the backup (`ar[0] = temp;`), giving you the rotated array as `[84, 8, 5, 6, 2, 1, -1, -100, 425]`

**Step-5: Continue this process till the `numberOfRotations` becomes 0.**

**Complete operation**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] ar = {8, 5, 6, 2, 1, -1, -100, 425, 84};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotateToTheRight(ar)));
}

static int findTheSmallestElementIndex(int ar[]) {

    int index = 0;
    int min = ar[0];

    for(int i=1; i<ar.length; i++) {

        if(min > ar[i]) {
            min = ar[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    return index;
}

static int[] rotateToTheRight(int ar[]) {

    int numberOfRotations = ar.length - findTheSmallestElementIndex(ar);
    
    if(numberOfRotations == 0)
        return ar;
    
    while(numberOfRotations-- > 0) {
        
        int temp = ar[ar.length-1];
        
        for(int i=ar.length-1; i>0; i--) {
            
            ar[i] = ar[i-1];
        }
        
        ar[0] = temp;
    }
    
    return ar;
}
```

Comment: @WJS, I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to rotate the array is not working. This code follows the rule: *you must not create and use any new tables and you must not use any additional Java classes* (except `System` and `Arrays` for printing). See the code comments.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void rotateLeft(int [] array, int amount)
    {
        // Rotate the array by 1, n times
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            // Save the first val
            int first = array[0];
            // Shift the array left 1
            // Ex: [1,2,3,4] -> [2,3,4,4]
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
            }
            // Put the value that was at index 0 in the last index
            // Ex: first = 1, [2,3,4,4] -> [2,3,4,1]
            array[array.length - 1] = first;
        }
    }
    
    // Different code when using a 2nd array
    public static int[] rotateLeft2(int [] array, int amount)
    {
        int [] newArray = new int[array.length];
        // Copy starting from the index of smallest value
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = amount; i < array.length; i++) {
            newArray[j++] = array[i];
        }
        // Copy from begining up to index of smallest
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            newArray[j++] = array[i];
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    // Find the index of the minimum value in the array
    public static int arrayMinIndex(int [] array)
    {
        int min = array[0];
        int minIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < min) {
                min = array[i];
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return minIndex;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array = {8,5,6,2,1,-1,-100,425,84};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        //rotateLeft(array, arrayMinIndex(array));
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        int [] b = rotateLeft2(a, arrayMinIndex(a));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[8, 5, 6, 2, 1, -1, -100, 425, 84]
[-100, 425, 84, 8, 5, 6, 2, 1, -1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped me a lot, But now I have a problem, because I have a program that test if the code is working(the tests I put up there), and they have a line of code that goes "int[] b=premakni(a);". That doesnt work with the code you have given me because the method is void and doesnt return any value. If I change it from void to int[], and return "array", it changes the "a" array, but my tests require that it doesnt do that. Is there a way to solve this? I hope you understand my question.

Comment: You would have to change `rotateLeft` to create a new array that is the same size as the old array and return that. Being able to create a new array, would change the code a bit. I can update. (But what happened to _you must not create and use any new tables_??)

Comment: I understand what you said, you dont have to update I can do it myself. Thats why I am so confused, because I cant change the "a" array and cant create a new array. Either way thank you for your help

Comment: That's ok. I already wrote the new code by the time you wrote your comment.